# js.erb file is not been rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax call on Ruby on Rails. When I select 2 collection_select's the third has to be rendered by Ajax. I'm new to Ruby on Rails, so if anybody could help me, I'd be thankful.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@preco_servico) do |f| %>      

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :produto %>
    <%= collection_select(:preco_servico, :produto, Produto.order('tipo'), :tipo, :tipo) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" >
    <%= f.label "Análise" %>
    <%= collection_select(:preco_servico, :analise, TipoAnalise.order('tipo'), :tipo, :tipo) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id="parametro-select", :remote >
  </div>  
  ...
<% end %>
```

application.js:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    $("#preco_servico_analise").change(function() {
      var produto_id = $('select#preco_servico_produto :selected').val();  
      var analise_id = $('select#preco_servico_analise :selected').val();     
        $.get('/preco_servicos/update_parametro/' + produto_id + '/' + analise_id, function(data){                      
           $("#parametro-select").html(data);
        })
      return false;
    });
})
```

The method on controller:

```
def update_parametro
    @precos = PrecoServico.where(:analise => params[:analise], :produto => params[:produto])   

    @sub_parametros = [] 


    @precos.each do |preco|

      @sub_parametros = Parametro.where("nome NOT IN (?)", preco.parametro)

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

  end
```

I've already included the code below on application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

And the file update_parametro.js.erb:

```
sub_parametro <%= collection_select(:preco_servico, :parametro, @sub_parametros, :nome, :nome) %>
```

On console I get this:

> Started GET "/preco_servicos/update_parametro/produto2/analise2"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 23:25:21 -0200 Processing by
>   PrecoServicosController#update_parametro as */*   Parameters:
>   {"preco_servicos"=>"preco_servicos",
>   "update_parametro"=>"update_parametro", "produto"=>"produto2",
>   "analise"=>"análise2"}  PrecoServico Load (0.2ms) 
>   SELECT `preco_servicos`.* FROM `preco_servicos` WHERE
>   `preco_servicos`.`analise` = 'análise2' AND `preco_servicos`.`produto`
>   = 'produto2'   Rendered preco_servicos/update_parametro.js.erb (0.5ms) Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

It tells me it is rendered, but nothing changes on screen and nothing appears in firebug.

Comment: check the network tab on your browser's inspector, there MUST be something as the response for that $.get, if firebug doesn't help use chrome or opera but there should be some response (at least empty, but something). is that your whole .js.erb? is that valid js syntax??

Comment: Oh, thank you!! You were right!! That wasn't a js.erb file, but a html.erb. On controller I changed "format.js" to "format.html"